# Why does this string get changed

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
cards = ['K', 'Q', 'J', '10', 'Z']
holding = []
for card in cards:
    if card != 'Z':
        holding.extend(card)
print(holding)
```

Output is:

```py
['K', 'Q', 'J', '1', '0']
```

Why not `['K', 'Q', 'J', '10']`?

Comment: Because you used extend, not append.

Comment: It's clearly mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) what `extend` does.

Answer (score 3):

`.extend` iterates over the elements given to it and adds them one by one (see [link)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/).

You added `'10'` as a string and as such it iterates through every element in it. So, either use `.append` or enter 10 as an int (if that's ok with other pieces of your code).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers, using `extend()` caused the issue.

However, if you simply wanna remove all occurrences of "Z" you can simply use one-liner list comprehension like below:

```py
cards = ['K', 'Q', 'J', '10', 'Z']
holdings = [card for card in cards if card != 'Z']
print(holdings)
```

Output:

```
['K', 'Q', 'J', '10']
```

Read more about list comprehension [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2):

You meant to use `append()`:

```
cards = ['K', 'Q', 'J', '10', 'Z']
holding = []
for card in cards:
    if card != 'Z':
        holding.append(card)
print(holding)
```

The `extend()` method treats the parameter as an iterable and iterates over the parameter and adding each element. So the parameter `'10'` would be treated the same as `['1','0']`.